# Specific angular library doesn't build with prod settings

Tags: angular, angular5, ng2-date-countdown

I am using **[`ng2-date-countdown`](https://github.com/matheushf/ng2-date-countdown)** library in my application which is used to display some sort of *remaining time* functionality.

The problem is, this works well with `ng serve` but when I do `ng build --prod` then I get an error.

> **`Unexpected value 'CountDown in {projectDir}/node_modules/ng2-date-countdown/dist/countdown.d.ts' declared by the module 'AppModule in {projectDir}/src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@component annotation.`**

**My findings**

I had looked into the `package.json` file of the library and I see that following dependency has been added to it.

```
"@angular/common": "5.1.2",
"@angular/compiler": "5.1.2",
"@angular/core": "5.1.2",
"rxjs": "5.5.6",
```

which already exists in my application and version of `angular` dependencies is higher. With further readings, I got to know that multiple `angular` components causes above said error. Also, I assume that version mismatch can also cause this issue.

**My attempts**

I had already raised an **[`issue`](https://github.com/matheushf/ng2-date-countdown/blob/master/package.json)** in the repository, but I just got one suggestion at this moment saying to build it with `--aot=false`, which as of my knowledge effects the performance of the application.

I also tried to fork the GitHub repo and build by own version of it by removing dependencies from the `package.json` but ultimately I kept on failing as I couldn't get much knowledge on how to do it on own.

Could someone point me in the right direction with this issue? What else can I try to resolve this issue?

Last but not the least, below are the dependencies I've in my application.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.65",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.7.1",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^4.6.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng2-cookies": "^1.0.12",
    "ng2-date-countdown": "0.0.5",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-slick": "^0.1.3",
    "razorpay": "^1.6.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.3.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.47",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
}
```

**EDIT**

In my `app.module.ts` I've below specific code for `Countdown` library

```
import {CountDown} from "ng2-date-countdown";

@NgModule({
    imports:[....], //all other imports
    declarations: [
       AppComponent,
       ..........
       Countdown
    ]
})
```

Comment: Can you show your AppModule ?

Comment: @SurenSrapyan Its too huge, I can add it but it will make post ugly. Do you want to look into any specific piece of code in that?

Comment: Yes, the import of CountDown and its adding into the module

Comment: @SurenSrapyan Updated the post..

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem too  , best solution is not to use ng2-date-countdown , as a library component . just copy "countdown.ts" , "countdown.scss" and "countdown.html" from "/node_modules/ng2-date-countdown/src" and paste it to your app than import copied component

```js
import {CountDown} from "./components/countDown/countdown";
```

```
import {CountDown} from "./components/countDown/countdown";
```

Comment: While this might work in a way, its good to use the library as the bundled size might be reduced..